# Wrapping react-redux's connect function in TypeScript results in compilation error

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to wrap react-redux's `connect` function into a helper function for a test utility.

Below is a simplified example:

```js
interface IProps {
  number: number
}

class NumberDisplay extends React.PureComponent<IProps> {
  render() {
    return `${this.props.number}`
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  return {number: 1}
}
```

The following works as expected:

```js
const ConnectedNumberDisplay1 = connect(mapStateToProps)(NumberDisplay)
export const display1 = <ConnectedNumberDisplay1 />
```

and it provides helpful type checks: if `number` is never set, the compilation will fail.

My wrap function looks like this:

```js
function wrap<StateProps, ComponentProps>(
  mapStateToProps: (state: any) => StateProps,
  Component: React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>
) {
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
                               // ^^^^^^^^^ Error happens here
}

const ConnectedNumberDisplay2 = conn(mapStateToProps, NumberDisplay)
export const display2 = <ConnectedNumberDisplay2 />
```

This is the error:

```
Argument of type 'ComponentType<ComponentProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<ComponentProps, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<ComponentProps, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>, any>'.
      Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
        Type 'WeakValidationMap<ComponentProps> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>> | undefined'.
          Type 'WeakValidationMap<ComponentProps>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>>'.
            Type '(null extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : Validator<ComponentProps[K]>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(null extends Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] ? Validator<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>) | undefined'.
              Type 'null extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : Validator<ComponentProps[K]>' is not assignable to type '(null extends Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] ? Validator<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>) | undefined'.
                Type 'Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> | (undefined extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : Validator<ComponentProps[K]>)' is not assignable to type '(null extends Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] ? Validator<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>) | undefined'.
                  Type 'Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'null extends Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] ? Validator<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>'.
                    Type 'null extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends ComponentProps[K] ? Validator<ComponentProps[K] | null | undefined> : Validator<ComponentProps[K]>' is not assignable to type 'null extends Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] ? Validator<Matching<StateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, ComponentProps>[K] | null | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>'.
```

As a temporary workaround, I'm using something like this:

```js
function wrap<StateProps, ComponentProps>(
  mapStateToProps: (state: any) => StateProps,
  Component: React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>,
): React.ComponentType<
  Omit<ComponentProps, keyof StateProps & keyof ComponentProps>> {
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Component as any) as any
```

But I'd prefer not to use `any` if possible. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've got a similar problem. Can you please check what version of `@types/react` you have installed? In my case it works with `@types/react@16.7.13`, but not `@types/react@16.7.14` (or later), when that `WeakValidationMap` has been added, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/c2367fab52cf48fafa9daa915f0714a81d3c122f#diff-96b72df8b13a8a590e4f160cbc51f40c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm using now and I do not get any compile errors with TypeScript 3.6.3:

```js
import { connect, GetProps, MapDispatchToPropsParam, Matching, ResolveThunks } from 'react-redux'

export type SelectState<GlobalState, StateSlice>
  = (state: GlobalState) => StateSlice

export function wrap<
    LocalState,
    State,
    Props,
    StateProps,
    DispatchProps,
    C extends React.ComponentType<
      Matching<StateProps & ResolveThunks<DispatchProps>, GetProps<C>>>
>(
  getLocalState: SelectState<State, LocalState>,
  mapStateToProps: (state: LocalState) => StateProps,
  mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<DispatchProps, Props>,
  Component: C,
) {
  return connect(
    (state: State) => {
      const l = getLocalState(state)
      return mapStateToProps(l)
    },
    mapDispatchToProps,
  )(Component)
}
```